# How do you not pass a value to a component in nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I'm probably doing something wrong but I'm following the official doc.
I want this component to be static and for me to be able to call it on any page, but as it is, it needs a parameter and I don't want to pass this parameter on the page where I'm calling the component. Is there a way to do it?

component:

```
import { GetStaticProps, InferGetServerSidePropsType } from "next"

type PersonalitiesProps = {
  id: string,
  name: string,
  historia: string
}

export const getStaticProps = (async (contexte) => {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/personalidades', {
    method: "GET",
  })
  const data = await res.json()
  return { props: { data } }
}) satisfies GetStaticProps<{
  data: PersonalitiesProps
}>

const Personalities = (data: InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) => {
  return data
}

export default Personalities
```

app/pages.tsx:

```
import Personalities from '@/components/Personalities'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <section>
      <h1>Hello, Word!</h1>
      <Personalities />
    </section>
  )
}
```

errors:

**Property 'data' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ data: any; }'.ts(2741)
index.tsx(14, 21): 'data' is declared here.**

**Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

I'm following the steps in this documentation, even though my project is nextjs ^14.0 and it's APP ROUTE:

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-static-props

Answer (score 1):

No offense but your code is ruining next.js

- `getStaticProps` is called only at pages, at build time. I dont understand how you are getting this error:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array
> instead.

because `Personalities` should be returning undefined, since `getStaticProps` will never get called automatically in components.

- `getStaticProps` are removed after next.js 13.

after next.js 13, there are no more server side functions that called automatically. before, next.js was going through all the routes and calling the special server functions and then build the page. now, if you are on the server component, (in client components, fetching are done `useEffect` or upon button press), you define a function and call it on your own.

```
function myFetching(){
   // do operation here
}
export default async YourPage(){
  // I can call await because server components can be marked async
  const result= await myFetching()

  return (
    // inside jsx you can use `result`variable
  )
}
```

By default, all routes are static in next.js. However, when you fetch data in a route, that route becomes dynamic because your `result` variable is a dynamic variable. however, next.js enhanced the [fetch api](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/fetch). example from the link:

```
export default async function Page() {
  // This request should be cached until manually invalidated.
  // Similar to `getStaticProps`.
  // `force-cache` is the default and can be omitted.
  const staticData = await fetch(`https://...`, { cache: 'force-cache' })
 
  // This request should be refetched on every request.
  // Similar to `getServerSideProps`.
  const dynamicData = await fetch(`https://...`, { cache: 'no-store' })
 
  // This request should be cached with a lifetime of 10 seconds.
  // Similar to `getStaticProps` with the `revalidate` option.
  const revalidatedData = await fetch(`https://...`, {
    next: { revalidate: 10 },
  })
 
  return <div>...</div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the education, some people here are not very kind with words (they comment on RTFM, in some questions), so how do I render data from an api in a component statically or not? So in next js 14, is there any way I can do something similar?

Comment: i edited the answer to explain better

Answer (score 0):

you have to make the prop data optional, by using '?' afer it's declaration.

```
const Personalities = (data?: InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) => {
  return data
}
```

now you can use the componente using or not the prop data.

Comment: I believe it's not just that, the error is this:
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.